# android rotation of an object and extra spacing

Tags: android, rotation

I need to get rid of all the extra spacing that's created after the rotation?
It seems the element keeps it's original width instead of using it's original height as the new width.

Suggestions would be welcomed.

[image]

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply any animation to component.

It shows that you have moved that component.

But actually that **components retains its original position**.

It does not moves from his original position.

You can say its android limitation.

But now it is solved in **API level 3.0**

You can try **3.0 or above.**

for more read [this](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.0.html)

Comment: I've tried raising the minSdkVersion to 14 (Android 4) but I get the same result. the original width of the object does not change, if I could align the button to the right so it would minimize the space that would be good as well.